# PHP upgrade causes MYSQLI pass by reference error

Tags: php, mysqli, pass-by-reference

This was a reported bug that I'm trying to work around, client has just upgrade from PHP V-whoknowswhat
to PHP V5.3. I believe this error here is one of many that is messing up the site. Anyway, long story short,
I need to pass $params as a reference instead of as a value, but I'm confused how to do it? Maybe some
help?

**Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in ../Zend/Db/Statement/Mysqli.php**

```
public function _execute(array $params = null)
{

var_export ($params);
// output1: array ( )
/* output2: array ( 
     0 => '34',
     1 => 'Four Seasons Seattle',
     2 => 'Four Seasons Seattle',
     3 => '{//...copy text...}',
     4 => '1',
     5 => '1',
     6 => 'four-seasons-hotel',
     7 => '14',
)
*/

    if (!$this->_stmt) {
        return false;
    }
    // if no params were given as an argument to execute(),
    // then default to the _bindParam array
    if ($params === null) {
        $params = $this->_bindParam;
    }


    // send $params as input parameters to the statement
    if ($params) {
        array_unshift($params, str_repeat('s', count($params)));

var_export ($params);
// output1: array ( )
/* output2: array ( 
     0 => 'ssssssss',
     1 => '34',
     2 => 'Four Seasons Seattle',
     3 => 'Four Seasons Seattle',
     4 => '{//...copy text...}',
     5 => '1',
     6 => '1',
     7 => 'four-seasons-hotel',
     8 => '14',
)
*/
        call_user_func_array(
            array($this->_stmt, 'bind_param'),
            $params
        );
die();

    }
```

Here's the bug report, i tried the lazy way that it talks about and it just whitescreened me without error =(

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43568

Comment: What does $params contain before it enters that code?

Comment: What the bind_param wants is a list of variables after param 1.  Internally, it then binds the result set to the variables so that when fetched will be updated without having to do anything else.  You can not pass in an array of string constants where the code expects variables to bind to.  I'm assuming this was coded in order to provide a generic wrapper, that would reuse the same code no matter the type of query.  For that reason, I hesitate to give you a solution that might work for what appears to be an insert or update, when that would not work at all for a select.  I'd amend the class.

Comment: Look at the note by nick9v at hotmail dot com on the http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php for an example of type of thing that would remedy your issue.  This could easily be made part of the existing class, or you could use Dependency injection, but in either case, you will need to update the class definition in addition to this specific method.  In doing so, you'd probably eliminate the passing in of the param as an array, make it a class variable and set each parameter by reference.

Comment: what did your error-log say when you got the white page? Also, the bug you link to has a lot of answers and fixes. didn't any of that stuff help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to completely rewrite the bindParams function to pass values by reference.
Code below.

```
private static function _bindParams(&$stmt, $valuesArray)
{
    if (count($valuesArray) > 0)
    {

        $types = str_repeat('s', count($valuesArray));
        $params = array_merge(array($types), $valuesArray);

        $tmpArray = array();
        foreach ($params as $i => $value)
        {
            $tmpArray[$i] = &$params[$i];
        }

        $bindOK = call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_param'), $tmpArray);
    }
    else
    {
        $bindOK = true;
    }
    return $bindOK;
}
```